# MVC EditorFor inside Another EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I have an EditorFor Template for a Model Role as below. I also have EditorFor for Date which works fine when I use EditorFor directly from View but when I have EditoFor inside an editor for it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl[ucsrManagementSystem.Models.ContactsInMailingListsViewModel]"

Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsInMainlingList)  
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Id)  
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)  
Html.EditorFor(m => m.EndDate)//This is not showing Date's Editor Template when inside another EditorFor
```

Comment: Could you post the other template too, the date template, and a snippet of the model?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me either; I'm presuming that it's some kind of anti-recursion protection.

If you change the outer call to 'EditorFor' to a 'Partial' instead - even pointing at the same .cshtml file - the inner 'EditorFor's will work.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now
        });
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

Editor template for MyViewModel (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.MyViewModel>" %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date) %>
```

Editor template for DateTime (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>
<div>Some markup to edit date</div>
```